# how to make child visible out of parent boundary (while dragging SVG Polygon point)

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, polygon

I have a parent-div and inside which I draw SVG Polygon.

The functionality is like, I should be able to grab & drag a polygon point any where (which is working fine). If, by any chance, we try to move and drop a point out side of the parent-div, parent-div will be resized automatically (as expected).

The problem is, when I try to move point out side of the parent-div, the part of polygon shape gets clipped. **OR** that point is obviously not visible as it moves out of the parent boundary since SVG is a child of parent-div.

What I want is, the point (and polygon shape) which is being dragged out side of the parent div, should be visible.

Is it possible to show point (being dragged out side of the parent div) ?
I though to play with Z-Index also but I don't know how to play with SVG-z-index.

If it is possible then how ?

I played with overflow/z-index property but it didn't work for some reason.

```
<div style="width:100px;
            height:100px;
            left: 400px;
            top: 100px;
            position: relative;" 
     
            class="resize-div" >
    
   <svg height="100%" width="100%">
     <g class="polygon"></g>  
   </svg>
  
  
</div>
```

.css

```
svg {
  position:relative;
}
.resize-div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 4px;
  resize: both;
}
.polygon {
  stroke: yellow;
  stroke-width: 10;
  fill: red;
}
```

**[DEMO Application](https://codepen.io/micronyks/pen/LYZbQbG)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`overflow:visible`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/overflow) on the SVG. This **removes** the clip applied on the SVG.

```
svg {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/xy2iii/pen/wvWXZrL)

Comment: It was so simple. Thanks for indicating it. I made myself fool many times to achieve this behavior.